# How to set up Next js App Router + i18n without language showing inside url

Tags: next.js, internationalization, i18next, app-router

So my goal is to have

- Next js pages rendered on the backend
- use App Router
- **do not** show language in url

Official Next.js internationalization proposes us to have intl setup like this

> english: https://yoursite.com
> polish: https://yoursite.com/pl
> french: https://yoursite.com/fr

I do not want to use this approach. Instead I want users to set language for themselves in profile and website always have the url `https://yoursite.com` (for non-english languages too)
**And** use pregenerated translated pages where possible

I had this done up with /pages
I used

- next-i18next
- cookies
- middleware.ts
  in middleware I checked cookies, detected request preferred language and did NextResponse.rewrite() to return user pages in language he chose.

For some reason this approach doesn't work with new /app router, when user is on home page (`'/'`) middleware doesn't redirect him to `[locale]/page.tsx` path even after rewrite.

is there some way to do it?